# which solution of critical section is fulfilled in this algorithm

Tags: operating-system, critical-section

initial value of flag is
 flag[2] is false

```
Process P0
do {
flag[0] = true;while (flag[1]) ;
<CS>
flag [0] = false;
<RS>
} while (1);




Process P1
do {
 flag[1] = true;while (flag[0]) ;   
<CS>
flag [1] = false;
<RS>
} while (1);
```

i want to know that if both processes run at the same time then isn't progress condition false?

My reason is that it creates a deadlock b/w two processes to get into critical section.
I also want to know is mutual exclusion is being fulfilled there?

Comment: Please include your code as text (code-block), not as an image.

Comment: ok please wait for a moment